# making linegoal pay attention to equation numbering

Tags: tabularx, linegoal

`linegoal` is an incredibly useful package. Is there a way to make it take equation numbering into account? Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,linegoal}
\begin{document}

\noindent
(1)% 
\begin{tabularx}\linegoal{|X}
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  blah blah 
\end{tabularx}

\begin{align}
  \begin{tabularx}\linegoal{|X}
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: linegoal!]

As you can see, `linegoal` is ignoring the `align` environment's equation numbering when it calculates the width of the "rest of the line". Is there any way around this -- that is, to make the second example look more like the first?

Updated to add: I suppose I am not after a result that looks **exactly** like the first. That is, I take it that the `align` numbering includes the actual text `(1)`, along with some whitespace to its right. I'm hoping to have all that taken into account by `linegoal`.

Comment: The equation number is assigned after the equation has been typeset, which can have an impact on the “line goal”. That the “equation” is a table or anything else is completely immaterial. And `align` doesn't impose any size to the material; if it exceeds a certain treshold, it moves the equation number up (or down if `reqno` is used).

Comment: Thanks, though I don't quite understand what you're getting at with the last two sentences. Is trying to use`linegoal` to achieve the result I'm after barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Exactly: for `\linegoal` there is no way to know about the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic solution that accomplishes what I was after (expands a `tabularx` to the right margin inside a numbered equation environment):

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\newcommand{\ex}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mathindent\relax}{|@{}X@{}|}
    #1
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah 
\begin{align}
  \ex{%
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  
  }
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image]

I realize there are several 'examples' packages developed for linguistics that have similar functionality (e.g., `expex`, `linguex`, and so on), but for various reasons, I'm not able to use those (principally: it's important for me to have a solution that operates closely in tandem with equation environments, vis a vis numbering, spacing, etc). If you're in a similar boat, I hope you find this helpful.